# Amazon AWS with CentOS 6 HVM: password required with SSH

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, centos6, amazon-ami

I am having some strange authentication issues when trying to spin up an Amazon instance using CentOS 6 HVM.

[image: CentOS used]

For some reason, whenever I spin one up using a security group and a key / pem pair, I still have to supply a password when trying to ssh using the following command:

`$ ssh -i mypem.pem ec2-user@00.0.000.000`

This only occurs when using the CentOS type noted above. When I make a Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03 (HVM) using the same security group and key / pem pair, I do not have to type in a password. **Is there a reason for this? Are there additional steps I need to do to be allowed to log in without knowing the password?**

Comment: Turn on key-based authentication in the SSH config.

Comment: Are you talking about the SSH item in the security group? I already have that set. I don't see an option to update the SSH config when generating this instance in the AWS console.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the SSH config on the instance, somewhere like `/etc/sshd` (I'm not 100% certain what the file/folder is called in CentOS). You can't set it when launching an instance or in the security groups - it's baked into the AMI by whoever created the AMI.

Comment: See also: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-ssh-configuration-keypairs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CentOS 6 (x86_64) HVM AMI image is setup to allow ssh key based login as the root user, it is advisable to setting up a non root user for regular instance access.

Steps for implementing this: https://awsmp-usageinstructions.s3.amazonaws.com/CentOS_User_Add_Instructions.pdf

Ref: http://wiki.centos.org/Cloud/AWS

Comment: Yup! I read the usage instructions and saw that note! Thanks!